# How to add different text to TextView of each View renderable

Tags: android, sceneform

I am trying to create a Renderable View with a Text view. I am creating multiple copies of same RendrableView. When I try to change Text in any of the Renderable View, Change is reflected in all Views. Can anyone help me in this context?

Code snippet of view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/txts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:padding="4dp">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dimentionsTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And android Code is :

```
private void createTxtNode(Node parent, String value)
{
    Node dimentionNode = new Node();
    dimentionNode.setParent(parent);

    dimentionNode.setRenderable(dimentionsRenderableView.makeCopy());
    dimentionNode.setLocalPosition(Vector3.zero());
    dimentionNode.setLookDirection(c.getForward());
    dimentionNode.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f));
    ViewRenderable r = (ViewRenderable)dimentionNode.getRenderable();
    View v = r.getView();
    TextView dimention = v.findViewById(R.id.dimentionsTxt);

        dimention.setText(value);
}
```

Actual Output :
If I have 2 Renderable Views,
When I add 1st view 14 mtrs.

2nd Renderable View :
12mtrs, 12 mtrs. Means 14 mtrs is replaced by 12 mtrs.

Expected output is :
14mtrs, 12 mtrs.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I am also facing same issue, could you please help?

Comment: no I have nor found any solution on this

Comment: Thank you for the reply, seems we need to build renderable each time.